# Can't use /= on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

On a `numpy` array, why is it I can successfully use `/ 2`:

```
>>> a=np.array([2, 4, 6])
>>> a = a / 2
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

But I cannot use `a /= 2`?

```
>>> a=np.array([2, 4, 6])
>>> a /= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc true_divide
```

I've seen [numpy Issue 6464](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6464), but don't understand from reading it and the linked release notes the reason this doesn't work.

Is there any way to get `/=` to work as expected?

Comment: Note in the first case the new `a` is a float.  The second isn't allowed to change the dtype.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the change from `int` (which is how `a` is created) to `float` (which is the result of /) is not allowed when using `/=`. To "fix" this the `dtype` of `a` just has to be a float from the beginning:

```
a=np.array([2, 4, 6], dtype=np.float64)
a/=2
print(str(a))
>>>array([1., 2., 3.])
```

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the comments, `a / 2` produces a float array, but the type of `a` is integer. Since NumPy's assignment operators are optimized to reuse the same array (that is `a = a + 2` and `a += 2` are not *exactly* the same, the first creates a new array while the second just reuses the existing one), you can not use them when the result has a different dtype. If what you want is an integer division, you can use the `//=` assignment operation:

```
>>> a = np.array([2, 4, 6])
>>> a //= 2
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
```